# Is JavaFX 2.2 going to support GPU acceleration in Linux?

Tags: javafx-2

I've been experimenting with JavaFX, and I've found out that as of 2.2.0.b15, it uses GPU to provide improved font rendering. This makes a big difference for me. I intend to use it for visualization and animated UI features, so I'd like to know if GPU support will be provided in Linux.

I have come accross many statements that say that JavaFX will use my GPU if it is supported, and it does, but only under Windows. I have not seen anything about hardware acceleration for graphics under Linux, so I'm curious, can I expect to have this with 2.2 release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe JavaFX for Linux already supports hardware acceleration for some features based on this statement from the [JavaFX 2.1 Linux Develop Preview Release Notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/release_notes_linux/jfxpub-release_notes_linux.htm):

> 3D features are supported for Nvidia cards (proprietary drivers only).

Not entirely conclusive, as it does not explicitly mention hardware acceleration, but I think use of hardware acceleration is likely if you have the appropriate Nvidia card and driver installed.  Potentially, over time, hardware acceleration support under Linux for other hardware and driver configurations may be added.

Comment: Thank you, I've missed this. Well, I have a card that belongs to geforce 10 series, and I'm using the proprietary drivers under Ubuntu. I can't see font rendering using the GPU as it does on Windows, so maybe we'll have to wait for the 2.2 GA release to see if it will work.

Comment: You might want to file an issue (check first if already one exists), so it doesn't get missed: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa